# Search Files using "if else" method based on User selection using drop down

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to Visual Basic. I have VB macro code which searches files based on user selection using drop down menu and returns the value.

Below is the code snippet:

```
Sub GetDataFromClosedBook()

    Dim mydata As String
    Dim mydata1 As String

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wkb1 As Workbook

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    ' I need to add if else loop here,
    ' when 'mydata' is not found jump to 'mydata1'
    ' and return the value

    mydata = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\" & Range("A1") & Range("A2") & Range("A3") & Range("A4") & ".csv"
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(mydata)
    wkb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1")
    wkb.Close False

    mydata1 = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\" & Range("B1") & Range("B2") & Range("B3") & Range("B4") & ".csv"
    Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open(mydata1)
    wkb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")
    wkb1.Close False

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Could you clarify in which language you'd like a solution? vbs / vba / vb.net ?

Comment: Hi There. If you are simply looking to see if a file exists then use the following: If(Dir(mydata )) = "" Then go to myData1

Comment: Thanks for valuable reply. I want in Visual basic Script Language

Comment: Ok. For VBS if you want to check if a file exits then do the following: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FileExists(path)) Then See below for modified code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to retrieve files based on dropdown selection Using Do while loop.

Here is the code Snippet.

```
Do While Filename <> ""
On Error Resume Next
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(mydata & Filename)
wkb.Sheets(1).Range("D8").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H6")
wkb.Close False
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Unable to open file " & Filename)
        Err.Clear
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Do
Filename = Dir
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydata = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\" & Range("A1") &  Range("A2") & Range  ("A3") & Range("A4") & ".csv"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


If (fso.FileExists(mydata)) Then
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(mydata)
    wkb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Copy 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1")
    wkb.Close False
else
    mydata1 = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\" & Range("B1") & Range("B2") & Range("B3") & Range("B4") & ".csv"    

    Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open(mydata1)
    wkb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Copy 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")
    wkb1.Close False
end if

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```